# Why can't I answer any protected questions on Stack Overflow even though I have 533 reputation?

Tags: bug, reputation, answers, privileges, protected-questions

You need 10 reputation to answer protected questions. I know that they ignore the Association Bonus, but I'm still 433 reputation over the requirement.

I don't see an answer box on any protected questions. For example, here's a random protected question: [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

[image]

A screenshot is:

[image]

No answer box at the bottom!

It's not that I want to answer that specific question, I'm just reporting a bug.

Comment: Are you trying to answer a *locked* question?  Nobody can answer locked questions.  Is the question closed, in addition to being protected?

Comment: Just a protected one that says you need 10 reputation.

Comment: Do you have any plug-ins/extensions/user scripts installed? What happens when you disable them all?

Comment: @Oded I doubt very much that any extensions can prevent you from answering protected questions on SE. That's ridiculous xD

Comment: @Narawa What? That's actually pretty strange.

Comment: @nicael - you'd be surprised at what some extensions do to a page. Just trying to rule out things.

Comment: I disabled the extensions and it's still like that. My extensions are for Chrome: Stylish, Color Picker, AdBlock Super.

Comment: Strangely there is also no protection notice in your screenshot.

Comment: @Narawa Maybe try in another browser?

Comment: @Oded right - it should be at the top when you actually can answer. The answer form is somehow not shown anyway.

Comment: consider also checking whether you are indeed logged in - I sometimes bump into that by mistake

Comment: It's something to do with the account, because how can I check my reputation if I'm logged out? Firefox shows the same thing.

Comment: I do wonder if a reboot will fix the issue (not kidding).

Comment: Since when has Oded been outsourced to India?

Comment: @gnat while not logged in, you see "share/improve this answer" instead of "share/edit/flag" (seen in the screenshots).

Comment: @BlasSoriano good catch; screen shot sufficiently proves that OP is logged in

Comment: @Servy - I've seen stranger reports (every S on the page is blank, on multiple browsers on a linux box. A reboot later and they are back).

Comment: @Oded Was just giving you a hard time ;)

Comment: Okay, but it's not about all that reboot/glitchy stuff, it's just that having sufficient reputation won't let me answer protected questions.

Comment: Have you actually tried that, @Narawa? Did you reboot? Still seeing the same? Reason we are asking is that non of us ever saw anything like that, and personally, I would like to rule out your machine having some weird memory issues at the moment.

Comment: I tried that on another computer though.

Comment: This is happening on multiple computers? Same network/ISP?

Comment: No I mean this happens on my Stack Exchange account.

Comment: Does it happen in other protected questions, or only that specific question?

Comment: All protected questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's ridiculous in any way seen. Try to execute my answer-form-adding JavaScript:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByClassName("bottom-notice")[0].innerHTML='<form%20id="post-form"%20action="/questions/'+window.location.href.split('/')[4]+'/answer/submit"%20method="post"%20class="post-form"><input%20type="hidden"%20id="post-id"%20value="'+window.location.href.split('/')[4]+'"><input%20type="hidden"%20id="qualityBanWarningShown"%20name="qualityBanWarningShown"%20value="false"><h2%20class="space">Your%20Answer</h2><script>StackExchange.ready(function()%20{initTagRenderer("bug%20feature-request%20discussion%20support".split("%20"),%20"faq%20status-completed%20status-declined%20status-bydesign%20status-norepro%20status-reproduced%20status-planned%20status-deferred%20status-review%20featured%20community-ads".split("%20"));prepareEditor({heartbeatType:%20\'answer\',bindNavPrevention:%20true,postfix:%20"",onDemand:%20false,discardSelector:%20".discard-answer"});});</script><div%20id="post-editor"%20class="post-editor"><div%20style="position:%20relative;"><div%20class="wmd-container"><div%20id="wmd-button-bar"%20class="wmd-button-bar"><ul%20id="wmd-button-row"%20class="wmd-button-row"><li%20class="wmd-button"%20id="wmd-bold-button"%20title="Strong%20&lt;strong&gt;%20Ctrl+B"%20style="left:%200px;"><span%20style="background-position:%200px%200px;"></span></li><li%20class="wmd-button"%20id="wmd-italic-button"%20title="Emphasis%20&lt;em&gt;%20Ctrl+I"%20style="left:%2025px;"><span%20style="background-position:%20-20px%200px;"></span></li><li%20class="wmd-spacer%20wmd-spacer1"%20id="wmd-spacer1"></li><li%20class="wmd-button"%20id="wmd-link-button"%20title="Hyperlink%20&lt;a&gt;%20Ctrl+L"%20style="left:%2075px;"><span%20style="background-position:%20-40px%200px;"></span></li><li%20class="wmd-button"%20id="wmd-quote-button"%20title="Blockquote%20&lt;blockquote&gt;%20Ctrl+Q"%20style="left:%20100px;"><span%20style="background-position:%20-60px%200px;"></span></li><li%20class="wmd-button"%20id="wmd-code-button"%20title="Code%20Sample%20&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;%20Ctrl+K"%20style="left:%20125px;"><span%20style="background-position:%20-80px%200px;"></span></li><li%20class="wmd-button"%20id="wmd-image-button"%20title="Image%20&lt;img&gt;%20Ctrl+G"%20style="left:%20150px;"><span%20style="background-position:%20-100px%200px;"></span></li><li%20class="wmd-spacer%20wmd-spacer2"%20id="wmd-spacer2"></li><li%20class="wmd-button"%20id="wmd-olist-button"%20title="Numbered%20List%20&lt;ol&gt;%20Ctrl+O"%20style="left:%20200px;"><span%20style="background-position:%20-120px%200px;"></span></li><li%20class="wmd-button"%20id="wmd-ulist-button"%20title="Bulleted%20List%20&lt;ul&gt;%20Ctrl+U"%20style="left:%20225px;"><span%20style="background-position:%20-140px%200px;"></span></li><li%20class="wmd-button"%20id="wmd-heading-button"%20title="Heading%20&lt;h1&gt;/&lt;h2&gt;%20Ctrl+H"%20style="left:%20250px;"><span%20style="background-position:%20-160px%200px;"></span></li><li%20class="wmd-button"%20id="wmd-hr-button"%20title="Horizontal%20Rule%20&lt;hr&gt;%20Ctrl+R"%20style="left:%20275px;"><span%20style="background-position:%20-180px%200px;"></span></li><li%20class="wmd-spacer%20wmd-spacer3"%20id="wmd-spacer3"></li><li%20class="wmd-button"%20id="wmd-undo-button"%20title="Undo%20-%20Ctrl+Z"%20style="left:%20325px;"><span%20style="background-position:%20-200px%20-20px;"></span></li><li%20class="wmd-button"%20id="wmd-redo-button"%20title="Redo%20-%20Ctrl+Shift+Z"%20style="left:%20350px;"><span%20style="background-position:%20-220px%20-20px;"></span></li><li%20class="wmd-button%20wmd-help-button"%20id="wmd-help-button"%20title="Markdown%20Editing%20Help"%20style="right:%200px;"><span%20style="background-position:%20-240px%200px;"></span></li></ul></div><textarea%20id="wmd-input"%20class="wmd-input%20processed"%20name="post-text"%20cols="92"%20rows="15"%20tabindex="101"%20data-min-length=""></textarea><div%20class="grippie"%20style="margin-right:%201px;"></div></div></div><div%20class="fl"%20style="margin-top:%208px;%20height:24px;">&nbsp;</div><div%20id="draft-saved"%20class="draft-saved%20community-option%20fl"%20style="margin-top:%208px;%20height:24px;%20display:none;">draft%20saved</div><div%20id="draft-discarded"%20class="draft-discarded%20community-option%20fl"%20style="margin-top:%208px;%20height:24px;%20display:none;">draft%20discarded</div><div%20class="community-option"><input%20id="communitymode"%20name="communitymode"%20type="checkbox"><label%20for="communitymode"%20title="Marking%20an%20answer%20community%20wiki%20encourages%20others%20to%20edit%20it%20by%20lowering%20the%20reputation%20barrier%20required%20to%20edit.%20However,%20you%20will%20not%20gain%20any%20upvote%20reputation%20from%20it.%20This%20cannot%20be%20undone.">community%20wiki</label></div><div%20id="wmd-preview"%20class="wmd-preview"></div><div></div><div%20class="edit-block"><input%20id="fkey"%20name="fkey"%20type="hidden"%20value=""><input%20id="author"%20name="author"%20type="text"></div></div><div%20style="position:%20relative;"></div><div%20class="form-submit%20cbt"><input%20id="submit-button"%20type="submit"%20value="Post%20Your%20Answer"%20tabindex="110"><a%20href="#"%20class="discard-answer%20dno">discard</a></div></form>'
```

(Either from the top bar or console; if latter then remove `javascript:` prefix)

Then click "Post Answer." It should reload writing an additional answer form and saying "Body is missing". If it behaves this way, everything okay; you get the full-featured answer form.

If no form appears, execute the script again, fill the answer body with <s>some bloat</s> your answer and post - the disadvantage of this is the preview not working - but you can write in the answer form to another question and submit there.

Comment: @Narawa And, by the way, doesn't it work?

Comment: Yeah but this is a feature request to make the StackExchange people find a way to fix it. Your answer is good but this is to get the bug fix.

Comment: @Narawa Typically, feature requests are first answered by non-employees, sometimes so as to help OP.

Comment: @Narawa ...and bugs also :)

Comment: This did not work. First I had to use find/replace to replace all your "%20" with actual spaces, then the form showed up. But after submitting the answer, I got a message saying my action "looked suspicious" (can't argue with that), so the post was not saved.

Comment: @Felipe surely something has changed since I answered two years ago :)

Comment: I know haha, but still at the end of 2017 this looks like the most pertinent information you can find about the issue, so I figured I'd leave a comment to maybe help people save some time.